# Changing values of an embed tag?

Tags: javascript, embed

I would like to control the values in an embed tag, but can't find a way to do this in JavaScript.

From youtube...

```
<div id="watch-player" class="flash-player">

<embed 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    src="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vflJrftp4.swf"
    width="640" 
    id="movie_player" 
    height="390" 
...
>
</div>
```

How can I change the width and height values of the embed tag within the specified div id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var embedElem = document.getElementById("movie_player");
embedElem.setAttribute("height", "200");
embedElem.setAttribute("width", "300");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the tag (for example with `getElementsByTagName('embed')`, or however):

```
var embed = ... // however you want to get the embed tag
embed.setAttribute("width","1920");
embed.setAttribute("height","1200");
// or whichever attributes to change
```

Comment: It has an ID. IDs are unique, so there really is no need for him to use `getElementsByTagName`.